# Image classification using Deep Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have been working on building an image classification using Deep Learning. The code was running well in my Google Colab notebook up until recently that I get an error in this code:

```
cnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

cnn is the name of my model and it did run but now that code does not work. I get the error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'"
which I have tried to solve and even tried to copy the code on a new notebook. I am using the CIFAR10 dataset from the TensorFlow library but it does not work on my Kaggle notebook. What could be the issue and how do I solve this in both Google and Kaggle notebooks? This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#loading the CIFAR10 dataset
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)= datasets.cifar10.load_data()
X_train.shape

X_test.shape

#2D array
y_train.shape

y_train[:5]

#reshaping and flattening
y_train= y_train.reshape(-1, )
y_train[:5]

classes= ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

#normalize images by dividing them into their pixel values
X_train= X_train / 255
X_test= X_test / 255

from warnings import filters
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

#creating cnn model
cnn= models.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),

    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)),

    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

earlystopping_callback = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True
)

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

#opt= Adam(learning_rate= 0.01)
cnn.compile(
    optimizer= 'adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

cnn.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25, validation_split=0.2, callbacks= earlystopping_callback)

cnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

y_test= y_test.reshape(-1, )
y_test[:5]

y_pred= cnn.predict(X_test)
y_classes= [np.argmax(element) for element in y_pred]
y_classes[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a dataset error. first, check X_test and Y_test dataset shape and ensure there is no null value in it

Comment: the "X_test.shape" gives the output
```(10000, 32, 32, 3)```
and "y_test.shape" gives the output
```(10000, 1)```

Comment: Check for Null values in your dataset